# drag & drop from Window's explore to vscode directly doesn't work

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I wanna drag & drop a file from explore to directory opened in vscode.
But I can't do that. Is this common in windows?
I can do this via desktop (drag & drop from explore to desktop and then to vscode)
Buy it's very redundant..

Comment: drag the file over an editor pane, and the position of drop influences what happens, there a 4 possibilities, see the coloring of the editor

Comment: The color changes  to a little deeper color as normal but it doesn't affect.